# PyTorch Dataloader: Dataset complete in RAM

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I was wondering if the PyTorch Dataloader can also fetch the complete dataset into RAM so that performance does not suffer if there is enough RAM available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concrete example of previous answer:

```
class mydataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data['x'][index,:], self.data['y'][index,:]
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data['x'].shape[0]

torch_data_train = mydataset(data_train)
dataload_train = DataLoader(torch_data_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

Comment: Depending on context and size of data vs RAM, mmapping might help too: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-boost-pytorch-dataset-using-memory-mapped-files-6893bff27b99

Answer (score 4):

You can extend [torch.util.data.Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) and create your own Dataset implementation. In the `__init__` function of your custom dataset you can then load all data in a list or any other data structure, which will be fully loaded into ram. The `__getitem__` will then only access the structure and return a single item.